# Compilation errors when trying to do scons in util/tlm

Tags: gem5

I was trying to follow the README under util/tlm. Below are the steps completed:

1. scons build/ARM/gem5.opt - *completed*
2. scons --with-cxx-config --without-python --without-tcmalloc USE_SYSTEMC=0 build/ARM/libgem5_opt.so - *completed*
3. cd util/tlm
4. scons - *error*

when I do scons from within util/tlm I see the following error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking whether __i386__ is declared... (cached) no
Checking whether __x86_64__ is declared... (cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/tlm/sc_master_port.o -c -std=c++17 -DSC_INCLUDE_DYNAMIC_PROCESSES -DTRACING_ON -I/home/gem5/build/ARM -I/home/gem5/util/systemc/gem5_within_systemc -I/home/gem5/ext/systemc/src -Isrc -Iexamples/common build/tlm/sc_master_port.cc
build/tlm/sc_master_port.cc: In member function 'void Gem5SystemC::SCMasterPort::b_transport(tlm::tlm_generic_payload&, sc_core::sc_time&)':
build/tlm/sc_master_port.cc:278:32: error: 'gem5::sim_clock' has not been declared
         (double)(ticks / gem5::sim_clock::as_int::ps), sc_core::SC_PS);
                                ^~~~~~~~~
scons: *** [build/tlm/sc_master_port.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Can you please help me out with how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For the above bug, I added `#include "sim/core.hh"` in the file "util/tlm/src/sc_master_port.cc"
Post that there are some namespace errors in few different files which I resolved by adding "`using namespace gem5`"